# I want to iterate through the inner list of JSON object and display on HTML

Tags: html, json, spring

Currently, I could display only the outer list data and nothing from keyStats.
What I want that whenever the currentNumberOfEntries is greater than 0, I want to display the keyStats data also directly from the next row under the corresponding column header. Otherwise continue with the next data.

```
[{
  "cacheName" : "PIPELINE",
  "urlName" : null,
  "keyName" : null,
  "hits" : 0,
  "misses" : 0,
  "currentNumberOfEntries" : 0,
  "keyStats" : [ ]
}, {
  "cacheName" : "REQUEST",
  "urlName" : null,
  "keyName" : "key"
  "hits" : 2,
  "misses" : 4,
  "currentNumberOfEntries" : 3,
  "keyStats" : [ {
  "cacheName" : "REQUEST",
  "keyName" : "1722957",
  "hits" : 0,
  "misses" : 0
}, {
  "cacheName" : "REQUEST",
  "keyName" : "SummaryRequest",
  "hits" : 0,
  "misses" : 0
}, {
  "cacheName" : "REQUEST",
  "keyName" : "LOAD_SUMMARY",
  "hits" : 0,
  "misses" : 0
 } ]
}, {
  "cacheName" : "Filter",
  "urlName" : null,
  "keyName" : null,
  "hits" : 0,
  "misses" : 0,
  "currentNumberOfEntries" : 0,
  "keyStats" : [ ]
} ]
```

This is my column definition:

```
 columnDefs : [
{
field:'cacheName',
displayName:'   Cache Name          '
},{
field : 'currentNumberOfEntries',
displayName:'   Number of entries           '
},{
field : 'keyName',
displayName:'   Cache Key           ',
cellTemplate : '<a href>{{row.keyName}}</a>'
 },{
field : 'hits',
displayName:'   Number of Hits      '
 },{
field : 'misses',
displayName:'   Number of Misses    '
 } ]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What you're trying to achieve seem straight forward. Maybe you should let us know [what have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: It worked, I modified the list before sending it here exactly the way I wanted to display.